# Perl - $? shows 0 for a -1 return code on Windows 2008 64bit

Tags: perl, system

Using Strawberry Perl 5.12.3

Running manually:

```
E:\informatica\tools>infacmd isp ping -sn tt -re 0
[ICMD_10033] Command [ping] failed with error [[INFACMD_10053] Service [tt] Domain [dmt3-9-dom-poc] has failed to ping back.].

E:\informatica\tools>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1
```

When I run the same command through Perl's "system", the $? shows 0. Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $cmd = system("infacmd isp ping -sn tt -re 0");
if ($? == -1) {        
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";    
}    
elsif ($? & 127) {        
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n", ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';    
}    
else {        
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;    
}
```

Output:

```
[ICMD_10033] Command [ping] failed with error [[INFACMD_10053] Service [tt] Domain     [dmt3-9-dom-poc] has failed to ping back.].
child exited with value 0
```

The same on Windows 2003 32bit and ActiveState Perl 5.8.8 shows correct results.

Comment: I wonder how that's possible since `ExitThread` and `TerminateThread` take an *unsigned* integer.

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck with `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}` than with the emulation of unix's process status structure.

Comment: It also returns Zero. I am perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your manual test is not entirely sufficient, as the "errorlevel" variable can be shadowed or matters can otherwise be confused by usage of the shell, so your "infacmd" may not be exiting with the exit code that you think it is.

Your perl script is invoking this subprocess via the shell.  Does the behavior change if you invoke it directly instead?  (which is usually good practice...)

i.e. if you change the `system` line to this:

```
   my $cmd = system('infacmd', 'isp', 'ping', '-sn', 'tt', '-re', '0');
```

... is the behavior affected at all?

Comment: Contrary to the documentation, using the list form does not prevent the shell from being used on Windows. That said, it won't be used in this circumstance if `infacmd` can be launched without the shell.

Comment: That's very useful information.  Do you know if this is specific to ActivePerl or is this true also for strawberry perl and msys perl?

Comment: @Friend-Pal, I imagine it affects both AP and Strawberry, but not cygwin. Try `system("dir", "*")` to find out. It should fail according to the documentation.

Comment: @Friend-Pal, Note that `system({ 'dir' } 'dir', '*')` does fail as it should.

Comment: @Friend-Pal, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Same result. At this point I haven't tested on AP on Win2008 but AP on Win2003 returns 255 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should shift $? (I.e., divide it by 256) before doing the branch...

```
$res = $? >>8;
if ($res == -1)
....
```

According to [system definition in perlfunc](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perlfunc%3asystem)

EDIT: I have just read in perl 5 by examples (chapter: handling errors and signals) that on windows you cannot rely on $? To represent the exit state of pipes and system. this could well your case.

the suggestion is,then, to capture the command output and parse it to find out which is the error code...

```
 my $output = `mycmd 2>&1`;
 if ($output =~ /.....
```

Comment: while your response does conform to the perlfunc rules, IIRC, `0 / 256 == 0`

Comment: Thanks, putting $?>>8 before if did not work. As a last resort I will have to parse the output as you suggested but I am still searching for the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

That leaves [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess). If the exit code from this is zero, the exit code is zero.